# Python "in" Comparison of Strings of Different Word Length

Tags: python, comparison, string-comparison, comparison-operators

I am working through a database of names with possible duplicate entries and attempting to identify which we have two of, unfortunately the formatting is a bit less than optimal and some entries have their first name, middle name, last name or maiden names mashed into one string and some have just first and last.

I need a way to see if say 'John Marvulli' matches 'John Michael Marvulli' and be able to do an operation on those matches. However if you try:

```
>>> 'John Marvulli' in 'John Michael Marvulli'
False
```

It returns False. Is there an easy way to compare two strings in this manner to see if one name is contained in another?

Comment: use regex (unfortunately I would need some time to find out the exact regex you need, but regex is your friend

Comment: Fast answers are not surely the best. You're new on Stackoverflow, you'll learn that better answers often need a little more time to  be posted.

Comment: Reading "the formatting is a bit less than optimal ", i thought that there may be misspellings in the data base. My answer detects the matching of ``'John Michael Marvulli`` and ``'John Michael Marvvulli``. A condition put on the ratios computed by the ``SequenceMatcher``'s method ``ratio()`` makes it possible that the program detects the matching of ``John Michael Marvulli`` and ``'John Michael Marvvulli`` but doesn't react for ``Peter Michael Marvulli`` and ``John Michael Marvulli``.

Comment: yeah I was testing and noticed I'm missing a few

Comment: And then, what is your consclusion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently discovered the power of the `difflib` module.
Think this will hekp you:

```
import difflib

datab = ['Pnk Flooyd', 'John Marvulli',
         'Ld Zeppelin', 'John Michael Marvulli',
         'Led Zepelin', 'Beetles', 'Pink Fl',
         'Beatlez', 'Beatles', 'Poonk LLoyds',
         'Pook Loyds']
print datab
print


li = []
s = difflib.SequenceMatcher()

def yield_ratios(s,iterable):
    for x in iterable:
        s.set_seq1(x)
        yield s.ratio()

for text_item in datab:
    s.set_seq2(text_item)
    for gathered in li:
        if any(r>0.45 for r in yield_ratios(s,gathered)):
            gathered.append(text_item)
            break
    else:
        li.append([text_item])


for el in li:
    print el
```

result

```
['Pnk Flooyd', 'Pink Fl', 'Poonk LLoyds', 'Pook Loyds']
['John Marvulli', 'John Michael Marvulli']
['Ld Zeppelin', 'Led Zepelin']
['Beetles', 'Beatlez', 'Beatles']
```

Comment: is this case insensitive too?

Comment: I tested and the answer is yes. I listed the ratios of the strings ``'JOHN MARVULLI','JOHN MARVULLi','JOHN MARVULli','JOHN MARVUlli', 'JOHN MARVulli','JOHN MARvulli', 'JOHN MArvulli','JOHN Marvulli','JOHN marvulli','JOHn marvulli','JOhn marvulli','John marvulli','john marvulli'`` against **john marvulli** and it gives increasing numbers ``0.077 0.154 0.231 0.308 0.385 0.462 0.538 0.615 0.692 0.769 0.846 0.923 1.000``

Comment: @Joel Smith Excuse me, I have problem with english or logic: IT IS CASE SENSITIVE, since a SequenceMatcher instance see a difference between ``'JOHN MARVulli'`` and ``'JOHn marvulli'``. - Well, now, have you solved your problem ? Did my solution or another one bring you help ? Are there problems that remain ?

Comment: I'm working on implementing your solution but I have began tearing apart the difflib library to see how it works. Should be done soon.

Comment: @Joel Smith As I'm not anglophone, I went to (http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tear+apart) to learn the sense of "to tear apart". It is said that it means _"express a totally negative opinion of"_ . Isn't your sentence contradictory , then ?

Comment: @Joel Smith I draw your attention on the following point, which explains why I used ``s.set_seq2(text_item)`` firstly , algorithmically followed by ``s.set_seq1(x)`` in the ``yield_ratios()`` function: **"SequenceMatcher computes and caches detailed information about the second sequence, so if you want to compare one sequence against many sequences, use set_seq2() to set the commonly used sequence once and call set_seq1() repeatedly, once for each of the other sequences."** , from the doc

Comment: I don't mean tear apart in that sense. I mean that that I am trying to understand how it works.

Comment: @Joel OK - Well, if my answer has been of interest for you, could you consider to accept it ?

Answer (score 7):

You need to split the strings and look for the individual words:

```
>>> all(x in 'John Michael Marvulli'.split() for x in 'John Marvulli'.split())
True
```

Comment: I'd go for: `set('John Marvulli'.split()).issubset('John Michael Marvulli'.split())`

Comment: what if I wanted to do the reverse say return all users who's names are NOT in a list?

Comment: Add a `not` in front of the predicate. Or you could also use [`itertools.ifilterfalse`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilterfalse).

Comment: @Joel Smith @Wooble ``all(x in 'John Marvulli'.split() for x in 'John Michael Marvulli'.split())`` gives ``False`` though they match. Then it will be necessary to test the two orders.

Comment: @eyquem: indeed; I answered the question OP asked rather than trying to divine which XY Problem he's really trying to solve.

Comment: @Wooble You're using "XY problem" phrase erroneously for two reasons: **1)** In this phrase, X is a problem, Y is an **attempted** solution, and the XY problem itself is thinking that Y may be a solution to X, hence asking about Y instead of about X. So "XY problem" isn't a supposed _"real"_ problem that someone would have , but the actual problem he HAS. see (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) **2)** Presently, Joel has not an XY problem , since he exposes his actual problem and is aware that using ``in`` can't constitute a solution

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

n1 = "john Miller"
n1 = "john   Miller"

n2 = "johnas Miller"

n3 = "john doe Miller"
n4 = "john doe paul Miller"


regex = "john \\s*(\\w*\\s*)*\\s* Miller"
compiled=re.compile(regex)

print(compiled.search(n1)==None)
print(compiled.search(n2)==None)
print(compiled.search(n3)==None)
print(compiled.search(n4)==None)

'''
output:


False
True
False
False
'''
```